# Kestrel Certificate "no such file" on Linux containers works find on Windows containers

Tags: linux, docker, kestrel

I have constructed an aspnetcore webapp using https on docker windows containers with no issue.   When I modified it to run on Linux containers using http, there was no issue.

However, when I enabled https on the Linux container, kestrel throws an exception saying "no file found" for the certificate.   After searching I found at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/aspnetcore-docker-https-development.md

```
Note: The certificate name, in this case aspnetapp.pfx must match the project assembly name.
```

I renamed the certificate to match the assembly name exactly cased as it is.

Lets say the name is:

Company.RLG.Server.WebAPI.dll

I named the certificate file: "Company.RLG.Server.WebAPI.pfx".  For the purpose of my test app, I merely copied that to the /https folder.   (Later will be doing the volume sharing.)

My DockerFile section for the Kestrel environment vars is:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT="8001"
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="x"
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path="\https\Company.RLG.Server.WebAPI.pfx"
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+"
```

However, even thusly renamed, Kestrel complains:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
   at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
```

Searched and finding a lot of similar but not exact variations of this issue, none of which seem to apply to my case.

Questions, suggestions, and answers are appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally, the container user is root for this test app, so there should not be a hidden permissions issue

Comment: wish I could like this question twice because it saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DUH.

Sorry for the dumb question folks.   I caught the issue.

You see in the above I am putting backslashes into the path for the certificate.

I changed those to forward slashes, and everything is working now.

Comment: Every time I make this Gumby error I feel like I should put a knotted hankie on my head and shout "MY BRAIN HURTS!" especially given the headache I usually have by the time I figure it out.